# Why doesn't Kitty Pryde fall through the ground?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, kitty-pryde

Why doesn't Kitty Pryde fall through the floor when using her special powers to phase?  If she can move through walls, etc, surely she should just keep falling down.

Comment: The real answer for almost all stories where people are out of phase with matter in general but manage to walk around is bad writing. But that will be our secret...

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze Shouldn't a person out of phase be unaffected by gravity?

Comment: That is a good point. They might not phase through the floor, they might float, but on a spaceship or plane, they would also be left behind...

Comment: The other kicker for me is always "how do they breathe?" but I can shrug that off more easily than this.

Comment: @dlanod Kitty doesn't normally; she holds her breath.

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze Only if the space-ship accelerates.

Comment: @CodeInChaos or changes direction or decelerates..

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/how-come-patrick-swayze-didnt-fall-through-floorboards-in-ghost

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitty_Pryde#Powers_and_abilities):

> While phasing, she does not physically walk on surfaces, but rather interacts with the molecules of air above them, allowing her to ascend and descend, causing her to seemingly walk on air.

One could extrapolate that she interacts with other molecules to control how much she would phase through the ground, when she does so.

It has been shown, in a few stories, that she can walk high in the air, but she has to concentrate in order not to fall.

In *Uncanny X-Men* #143 (1981) it shows her "using her phasing ability to literally walk on individual molecules of air":

[image: Kitty Pryde walks on air]

Comment: Do we know whether that's explained in the comics, or is that just Wikipedia?

Comment: @dlanod http://www.flickr.com/photos/kaptainkobold/191181454/ here's an example of her walking on air in the comics.

Comment: Here it explains that she's interacting with the individual molecules http://www.flickr.com/photos/95492938@N00/181043130

Comment: @OghmaOsiris this second link appears to be wrong - it shows a gallery of photos with the tag "walkingonair"

Comment: I fixed it. It should work now.

Comment: So her "phasing ability" extends to everything except "air molecules"? Is that specifically Oxygen, Nitrogen or Carbon-dioxide? Or maybe Argon? It's funny how the suspension of disbelief allows us to accept mutants walking through walls, but floating on floors is one bridge too far :)

Comment: @pap my understanding is that she chooses the way to interact with some molecules - if she phased through every other kind of molecule, she would phase through the ground, as per the question.

One could think that she would need perfect perception of the molecules around her for that to work, but it is better not to think too much of it. :)